# MVP with Dagger 2 and common object

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using MVP pattern with Dagger 2.

My project has two features using a common repository. It means I have to inject two times this repository, one time for each feature. But when It tried to do this I get this error : ***"...Repository is bound multiple times"***

I found that this can be resolved using `@Named`. So I added this in my module but now I'm getting a new error *"...Repository cannot be provided without an `@Provides-annotated` method."*

I think I have to add this `@Named` elsewhere in my project to make it work properly since I got some link explaining this (like this one [multiple instance of same object with named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932780/dagger-2-error-while-getting-a-multiple-instances-of-same-object-with-named)). The problem I'm quite new to all this and can't find where to add this `@Names` elsewhere in my project architecture.

So, I'm actually getting this error *"...Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."*

My project is structured like following.

==== A **root package** containing this three classes :

**App class**

```
public class App extends Application {
    private ApplicationComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final String AUTH_TOKEN = getResources().getString(R.string.aqicn_token);
        final String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.aqicn_api_base_url);    

        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .pollutionApiModule(new PollutionApiModule(BASE_URL))
                .pollutionLevelsModule(new PollutionLevelsModule())
                .build();

    }

    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent class**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, PollutionApiModule.class, PollutionLevelsModule.class, DonutModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void injectPollutionLevels(PollutionLevelsFragment target);
    void injectDonut(DonutFragment target);

}
```

**ApplicationModule class**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Application application;
    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideContext() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

==== **A pollutionlevels package** containing a Dagger module, this package is MVP structured (Fragment, Model, Module, Presenter...) and is related to a single feature that get data from my common repository. The purpose of this feature is to show my data as text :

**PollutionLevelModule class**, you can see here I tried to add the @Name annotation trying to resolve my problem :

```
@Module
public class PollutionLevelsModule {
    @Provides
    public PollutionLevelsFragmentMVP.Presenter providePollutionLevelsFragmentPresenter(PollutionLevelsFragmentMVP.Model pollutionLevelsModel) {
        return new PollutionLevelsPresenter(pollutionLevelsModel);
    }

    @Provides
    public PollutionLevelsFragmentMVP.Model providePollutionLevelsFragmentModel(Repository repository) {
        return new PollutionLevelsModel(repository);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("levelsRepo")
    public Repository provideRepo(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        return new CommonRepository(pollutionApiService);
    }
}
```

This package contains a Fragment where I inject the repository in `onActivityCreated()`. Here I call the method `injectPollutionLevels()` implemented in my App class (the class I shew you just above) :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().injectPollutionLevels(this);
}
```

==== **A donut package** containing a Dagger module, this package is MVP structured (Fragment, Model, Module, Presenter...) and is related to a single feature that get data from my common repository. The purpose of this feature is to show my data as chart :

**DonutModule class**, you can see here I tried to add the @Name annotation trying to resolve my problem :

```
@Module
public class DonutModule {
    @Provides
    public DonutFragmentMVP.Presenter providedDonutFragmentPresenter(DonutFragmentMVP.Model donutModel) {
        return new DonutPresenter(donutModel);
    }

    @Provides
    public DonutFragmentMVP.Model provideDonutFragmentModel(Repository repository) {
        return new DonutModel(repository);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named ("donutRepo")
    public Repository provideRepo(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        return new CommonRepository(pollutionApiService);
    }
}
```

This package contains a Fragment where I inject the repository in `onActivityCreated()`. Here I call the method `injectDonut()` implemented in my App class (the class I shew you just above) :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().injectDonut(this);
}
```

**==== A common package containing my Repository**

```
public class CommonRepository implements Repository {
    private PollutionApiService pollutionApiService;

    public CommonRepository(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        this.pollutionApiService = pollutionApiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getDataFromNetwork(String city, String authToken) {
        Observable<Aqicn> aqicn = pollutionApiService.getPollutionObservable(city, authToken);

        return aqicn;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of my architecture if that can help you to point better how to solve this. Let me know if you need more source code. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you provide `@Named Repository`, you also need to ask for `@Named Repository`

```
@Provides
public DonutFragmentMVP.Model provideDonutFragmentModel(@Named("donutRepo") Repository repository) {
    return new DonutModel(repository);
}
```

Comment: So easy... I should be able to point this myself. Many thanks anyway.